# Need To Compare Files In Directory And Delete Similar Files (but it's more complicated than the norm)

Tags: windows, pdf, robocopy

so I have a rather odd need in my work environment and I'm having a lot of trouble figuring it out. I'll try to make this as short and sweet as possible, but explaining some background is key as to why things are challenging. Also, this is all in a Windows environment, since that's probably important lol.

So, I need a way to automatically move PDFs, once they have been edited, to specific folders. To do this, I'm planning on having the users edit the PDFs, and then do a save as and append a letter at the end. Something such as AB111d would go into the Done folder, but if it was AB111u it would go into the Uncompleted folder, for example. I've already figured this out via Robocopy, it's quite easy.

Now here is where the issue comes into play, the files are already named according to the naming structure we need when they are placed into the main folder, so the user is NOT having to rename the entire file, just appending a letter (speed is key here, so typing an entire name would be a significant time suck when these users are doing this 100s of times a day). But I ALSO need to delete (or move would work too) the original file within the directory that doesn't have the appended letter.

For example, a user opens AB111, works on it, saves as, and renames it to AB111d, the robocopy script I'm using moves AB111d to the Done folder, but AB111 is still in there, that original AB111 file is the file I need to delete somehow (again or move, it just needs to not be in the users working folder so they're aware they've already finished it). Whether this is scripted, or can happen at the time of saving as, either would work.

Is there any way to, say, compare files in a directory but WITHOUT the appended letter? So I could then compare the working directory to the Done directory (for example) but without the appended "d" on the Done directory files. And then delete/move the original file.

Final note, this all needs to be automated via scripting, and needs to happen at most every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

[Robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)
has the option of:

```
/mov    Moves files, and deletes them from the source after they are copied.
```

If you need to exclude files that are present in destination but not in source,
these are called "extra files".
Excluding extras will prevent any deletions from the destination.
The option for that is:

```
/xx     Excludes extra files and directories.
```

Comment: Hi there, I understand how to do that, the issue is that the newer files are named differently than the original file. So I can't simply exclude extras or anything like that since the names are different.

Comment: It would help to add your robocopy command to your post.

Comment: There isn't an issue with my commend, the command works fine, the issue is I'm not sure what to do with the residual files after the save as happens. Read through the post again, specifically the 2nd to last paragraph. The users are doing a save as on the files, so the original file is still there after robocopy runs. And I need a way to somehow get rid of that original file that has a DIFFERENT name than the new file, but I can only do this once that new file is created.

Comment: I can only comment meaningfuly if I know exactly what you do.